# When Returning 2 or more values from a Subroutine only the last varaible returns defined

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm currently writing a small Perl script to act as a cronjob.

The task of the Subroutinen is to check whether the file I'm writing to is a valid json file or not and to then proceed based on the return of this subroutine and the output of another Subroutine.

Even though I do return the multiple values in a list and then assign the result of the function to the list of variables that i want define, it only seams to work with the last value from the list.

I could just encapsulated the values with an array, but i want to knowe why the method i tried is not functioning as i expected.

(sorry for the bad formatting...)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;


sub is_valid_json {

 my $readJson = do {
     open(my $readJson, "+<", "../data_out.json")
         or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");
     local $/;
     <$readJson>
 };

 my $json = JSON->new;

 eval {

     my $result = $json->decode($readJson);
     my $JsonValidationStatus = 1;

     return($JsonValidationStatus,$readJson );
 } or do {
     warn "Failed to decode_json result";
     print "mission failled";
     my $JsonValidationStatus = 0;
     return($JsonValidationStatus, $readJson);
 };
}

 my ($JsonValidationStatus, $readJson) = is_valid_json();
 print "One:". Dumper  "$JsonValidationStatus\n";
 print  "Two:" . Dumper "$readJson\n";
 print "\n \n \n \n";
```

ps. sorry forgot to provide the error message:

> Use of uninitialized value $readJson in concatenation (.)

Comment: `return` inside an `eval` returns from the `eval`, not the subroutine.

Comment: now i just feel stupid... thanks anyway... should have known  it better.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but I think you could use Data::Dumper more gracefully:

print Data::Dumper->Dump([$JsonValidationStatus, $readJson], ['*One', '*Two']);

Comment: Thankful for any help that might improve upon my code/coding style  :D... Indeed i have to confess that you're way of writing is a lot more smoother and sexier. Am and  Matt Jacob would you like to make you're coment the answer of this thread. I cant axept it if its just a coment, and posting the answer my self  would be injust.